# How to access the attribute of a element when using rss in php

Tags: php, xml, twitter-bootstrap, rss

I am using a RSS-feed to display some news. But the thing is that i use bootstrap and the RSS-feed send a image that i cant figure out how to access, so i can putt `class="img-responsive"` on it. Now the images dosent fits to the screen..

php code when i collect the elments from the RSS-feed:

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET["q"];

    $xml=("https://www.gamereactor.se/rss/rss.php?texttype=4");

    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load($xml);

    $channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
    $channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo("<br>");
    echo($channel_desc."</p>");

    $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
    for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {$item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo ("<p><a href='".$item_link."'>".$item_title."</a>");
    echo ("<br>");
    echo ($item_desc);
    echo ("<img class=img-responsive>".$item_desc."<img></p>");} //where im trying to access the image..

 ?>
```

This how the xml from the RSS-feed looks:

```
<title>Nya Need for Speed kommer att kräva internetuppkoppling</title>
<description>&lt;img src=&quot;http://www.gamereactor.dk/media/55/_1455534.jpg&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;Svenska Ghost Games pillar för fullt med kommande Need for Speed som ska släppas till PC, Playstation 4 och Xbox One den 3:e november. Förutom att vi tidigare rapporterat...&lt;/p&gt;</description>
```

Comment: the rss feed doesn't contain an image. it contains some encoded html. you need to html_entity_decode() that text

Comment: Can u show a example? I tried the decode..

Comment: `html_entity_decode(gEBTN('description')->nodeValue)`, basically. there are no child nodes inside the descsription field in the rss. it's all just text.

Comment: I know im slow.. but i dont know how to use this.. html_entity_decode($item_desc). I tried to echo it, but i only get the same..

I want to know how to only display the image once in a <img> tag..

Comment: No one that can help me?? I really need some help with this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the data you get back. When you view the XML, you will see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media= "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<channel>
    <atom:link href="http://www.gamereactor.se/rss/rss.php?texttype=4" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <title>Gamereactor Sverige Nyheter</title>
    <link>http://www.gamereactor.se</link>
    <description>Dagsfärska nyheter, tunga artiklar, intervjuer, personliga bloggar, intressanta forumdiskussioner och rättvisa recensioner. Gamereactor är Sveriges största speltidning- och spelcommunity</description>
    <webMaster>kenneth.gant@gamereactor.dk (Kenneth Gant)</webMaster>
    <item>
        <link>http://www.gamereactor.se/nyheter/244164/Alla+f%F6rhandsbokningsbonusar+till+Arkham+Knight/?rs=rss</link>
        <guid>http://www.gamereactor.se/nyheter/244164/?rs=rss</guid>
        <title>Alla förhandsbokningsbonusar till Arkham Knight</title>
        <description>&lt;img src=&quot;http://www.gamereactor.dk/media/28/framtidensbatman_1102834.jpg&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;En flitig Reddit-besökare har tagit på sig att lista var och till vilket format du bör reservera Batman: Arkham Knight för att få den förhandsbokningsbonus just du vill...&lt;/p&gt;</description>
        <author>jonas@gamereactor.se (Jonas Mäki)</author>
        <pubDate>Fri, 29 May 2015 19:44:54 +0200</pubDate>
    </item>
```

So the `IMG` tag is within the description and encoded. So the following line will have this detail:

`$item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;`

To make use of this as HTML in your page, we want to do:

`$item_desc=html_entity_decode($x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);`

`$item_desc` will now contain: `<img src="http://www.gamereactor.dk/media/28/framtidensbatman_1102834.jpg"><p>En flitig Reddit-besökare har tagit på sig att lista var och till vilket format du bör reservera Batman: Arkham Knight för att få den förhandsbokningsbonus just du vill...</p>`

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET["q"];

    $xml=("https://www.gamereactor.se/rss/rss.php?texttype=4");

    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load($xml);

    $channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
    $channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo("<br>");
    echo($channel_desc."</p>");

    $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
    for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++){
        $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $item_desc=html_entity_decode($x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
        echo ("<p><a href='".$item_link."'>".$item_title."</a>");
        echo ("<br>");
        echo ($item_desc);
    }

 ?>
```